# How to size and position all images in a markdownfile with pandoc/latex?

Tags: image, latex, markdown, pandoc, pdflatex

i am looking for a way to resize all images in an existing markdown file e.g. i want all pictures to have a max width of 80% of the textblock width and have all the images centered and bordered. How do I do this and is there a way to customize borders, e.g. colors and width of that border?

This is an example of my markdown file:

```
# section
## subsection
### subsubsection



![dummy1](.\dummy1.jpg)

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting.

![dummy2](.\dummy2.png)



| Eigenschaft |             Typ             | Beschreibung                                                 |
| :---------: | :-------------------------: | :----------------------------------------------------------- |
|  `general`  | `object` <br/> *(optional)* | Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. |
|   `esri`    | `object` <br/> *(optional)* | Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. |
|  `webgen`   | `object` <br/> *(optional)* | Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. |
```

using pandoc and this shell script:

```
pandoc "$1" \
    -f gfm \
    --include-in-header chapter_break.tex \
    --highlight-style pygments\
    -V linkcolor:blue \
    -V geometry:a4paper \
    -V geometry:margin=2cm \
    -V mainfont="Arial" \
    -V monofont="Arial" \
    -o "$2"
```

and this tex file

```
\usepackage{sectsty}
\sectionfont{\clearpage}
```

i get this result

[image: page 1]

[image: page 2]

I am looking for a way using pandoc shellscript to get all pictures width scaled down to 80% text width.

Also I am looking for a solution to get the tabled formatted in the right way as its width is not right. But still using the

```
\usepackage{sectsty}
\sectionfont{\clearpage}
```

tex file. Thank you alot for your help!

Comment: Can you make a compilable [mre]?

Comment: manually: `![](myimage.png){width=80%}` or you can write a pandoc lua filter to add this attribute to all images...

Comment: I just added an example with codes and pictures. Looking forward to your help!

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz i just marked you, in case you forgot. Sorry, it would be alright if you cant help me here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the default with of the images using `\setkeys{Gin}{width=.8\linewidth}` and boarders can be added with the `floatrow` package:

```
\usepackage{sectsty}
\sectionfont{\clearpage}

\usepackage{floatrow}
\floatsetup[figure]{style=boxed} 

\setkeys{Gin}{width=.8\linewidth}
```

[image]

(please only ask one question per question. You can ask a new question for the unrelated problem about the table)

Answer (score -1):

If you aim at multiple output formats (e.g. Beamer and journal paper), I would recommend a Pandoc filter in LUA or Python that takes additional meta-data from the image and adjusts the width and height properties before passing this to the LaTeX engine.